# Setting ImageView source not working correctly

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am loading a new image into an imageview when the stop and play button is pressed. They toggle back and forth. However when I set the image source in my code is appears really wrong.

Before

[image]

Then I call

```
bottomBar.setImageResource(R.drawable.bottombuttonsstop);
```

End Result

[image]

Layout XML

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomBarBox"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bottombuttons"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Obviously this is not loading correctly for some reason, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call `setBackgroundResource` instead of `setImageResource` or set `android:src` in a layout file